# Guardar array SQL usando Symfony2 y Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, array, symfony2, doctrine2

Tengo en una entidad una columna de tipo array como esto:

```
@ORM\Column(name="acompanantes", type="array")

public fuction setAcompanantes(array $acompanantes)
```

{

```
$this->acompanantes = $acompanantes;
return $this;
```

}

```
public fuction getAcompanantes()
{
return array($this->acompanantes);
}
```

El resultado en la tabla mysql es de tipo tinyText  con comentario DC2Type:array, entiendo que esto esta bien pero ¿Cómo podría insertar los datos utilizando formulario de symfony2.8?¿Podríais ayudarme?

Comment: ¿acompañantes podría ser una entidad?

Comment: No, el problema que tengo es que no puede ser una entidad.

Comment: Hasta que piense en algo mejor, solo te puedo recomentar usar [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html), y tras procesar el formulario, tomar los valores y guardarlos en un array para pasarlos a la entidad en cuestión.

Comment: @Muriano - ¿Cómo guardaría los datos recogidos de la vista en el controlador?

Comment: Sabes usar el objeto form de symfony? Tras las validaciones oportunas que ejecuta cuando haces un `$form->handleRequest($request);` tienes disponible un objeto/array (depende de tu formulario) con los valores. Usa `$form->getData();` para acceder a ellos.